# Why is iCloud email deleted on iPad?

Tags: icloud, email

9 months of emails are gone from my iPad. 
They still appear on iCloud on my computer.

How can I restore them to iPad?

Comment: Is the mail option turned on for iCloud under settings?

Comment: or just try to delete/add email account again